# Foundation top bar - how reveal items on small screen

Tags: mobile, navigation, zurb-foundation

I'm building webapp focused on mobile. I want to have some navigation/action items displayed on topbar, but current logic of Foundation is hiding everything into sliding menu when on small screen. It is just annoying if my topbar items are hidden, when there is 500px of space on my tablet.

Please help, how reveal items on small screen when there is enough space to show them? Twitter Bootstrap have this functionality, it is easy as "not to nest items to `div.nav-collapse`".

I'm using Foundation 4.2.1, CSS only, no JS.

Comment: This has been a pain for me too. Is there a solution? Please ping me

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly then you can hop into the CSS and change the media-queries for show-for-small/show-for-medium and expand the medium size to include the resolution for ipads, but I might be misreading what you're wanting.

Comment: @Dylan yeah, I think this most straight-forward sollution. I was just asking if there is possibility to solve this in HTML, not CSS (SASS). You know, if I put (or not put) this menu items into this `div.class`, then it will not hide into sliding menu, instead stay on the screen.

Comment: @srigi  You are correct, you should be able to fix this with ONLY HTML however you have not given us any code to look at or fix. We need some sort of snippet or live link or even a jsFiddle of your code so that we can see if you are making a small mistake within the HTML. Until you do this there is nothing we can really help you with